# Problems with "updateMany" and "$pull" on array properties

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, insert-update, upsert

I have the following object in my mongodb:

```
{ 
  "item": {
    "id": "/Ed/6wigZ9LTLs2mPDWDzOFD/he0vbUEvQBl2Bga/T8=",
    "status": {
      "likes": [
        "HU0HKFoL2YQuQ2WrYhj0rYoFbRkwJ0EJEf4ML7vAp2Q="
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to update my collection, and pull the value "/Ed/6wigZ9LTLs2mPDWDzOFD/he0vbUEvQBl2Bga/T8=" from all documents in the collection who have this value in their `item.status.liles` array.

When I use the tool **Robo 3T**, I can put into the command line:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').update({"item.status.likes": "/Ed/6wigZ9LTLs2mPDWDzOFD/he0vbUEvQBl2Bga/T8=" }, { "$pull":{"item.status.likes": "/Ed/6wigZ9LTLs2mPDWDzOFD/he0vbUEvQBl2Bga/T8="}})
```

And it says `Updated 0 record(s) in 2ms` when I execute the command (which is correct, since there is no document matching).

Now when I do the same in **Node.JS** code, like this:

```
let filter = {item.status.likes: '/Ed/6wigZ9LTLs2mPDWDzOFD/he0vbUEvQBl2Bga/T8='};
let obj = {"$pull":{"item.status.likes":"/Ed/6wigZ9LTLs2mPDWDzOFD/he0vbUEvQBl2Bga/T8="}}

collection.updateMany(filter, obj, { upsert: true }, (err, info) => {...});
```

I get `MongoError: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value` instead.

If I change it to:

```
collection.updateMany({}, obj, { upsert: true }, (err, info) => {...});
```

I get no error. This leads me to believe that there is a difference between "no filter" and "empty result set", and $pull does not work on the latter.

Why is this? I also tried with different "$pull"-syntax (e.g. `{"item":{"status":{"likes"...` vs `item.status.likes`) but this didnt change anything.

Comment: Are you sure you want pull `/Ed/6wigZ9LTLs2mPDWDzOFD/he0vbUEvQBl2Bga/T8=` from likes?  It's not there. iI's item's id. The only item that can be pulled from likes in the example document is `HU0HKFoL2YQuQ2WrYhj0rYoFbRkwJ0EJEf4ML7vAp2Q=`.

Comment: Yes. The use case is that "delete 'my id' from all documents which have 'my id' in their 'likes' array". And in the above example, there is no matching other document, and thus, I get the error.
Once I change the filter to `{}` **or** add a second document with `/Ed/6wigZ9LTLs2mPDWDzOFD/he0vbUEvQBl2Bga/T8=` in the `likes`-array, it works. However for my implementation it _must_ work with empty result set, since this will often be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens when there is no single document matching the filter because of `upsert: true`.

It tells mongo to insert a new document with fields from the filter, which makes following document:

```
{ 
  "item": {
    "status": {
      "likes": "/Ed/6wigZ9LTLs2mPDWDzOFD/he0vbUEvQBl2Bga/T8="
    }
  }
}
```

Then it tries to apply the update to this document calling $pull on the string which results with the error.

The Robo3T version works because the update is `upsert: false` by default.

Comment: Thanks, worked. Indeed the `upsert: true` was pretty useless here too, so I could just remove it.